# elementary OS - JDK not found

Tags: jdk

I successfully installed Netbeans with JDK package in elementary OS and it works without any issues. I am now trying to install pycharm but getting error as JDK is not installed. Do I need to install JDK again?

Comment: Can you tell us what you get when you run `javac -version`?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility that I can think of is that you have OpenJDK installed, and PyCharm requires OracleJDK. I had a similar issue with Android Studio (also JetBrains product, so they might require the same things..). The solution, for me, was to install Oracle JDK. I used this no-fuss installer from WebUpd8: [Oracle Java (JDK) 7 / 8 / 9 Installer](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).